# Rails 6 on Heroku: ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Our Rails app has just been upgraded to Rails 6.0 but the deployment to Heroku fails with:

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
Running: rake assets:precompile
DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_b9759d496c72c1085bb8441e3c2159fb/config/application.rb:7)
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter   
/tmp/build_b9759d496c72c1085bb8441e3c2159fb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:163:in `spec'
```

config/database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_USER'] %>
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: OurApplication_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: OurApplication_test

production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Using version:

- rails (6.0.0)
- Ruby (2.6.5)

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved by adding the 'adapter' to 'production' in the database.yml. This wasn't necessary when our project was on Rails 4 and 5.

```
production:
 adapter: postgresql
```

Comment: Looks like you might have been missing this line ```<<: *default``` in your production section of the file, which adds the adapter automatically to your production config. This was probably there in your Rails 4 and 5 projects, I don't remember the adapter being optional.

Comment: This solved the issue in my app. I use the sqlite3 adapter in *default and inherit with `<<: *default` for development and test, but didn't specify an adapter in `production`, where I use postgres instead. This was fine in Rails 4 and 5 (and I think 3), but not in 6.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution altogether would just be to use `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]` to specify the connection details and keep your defaults segment to the actual minimal defaults:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: OurApplication_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: OurApplication_test

production:
  # doing url: is just stupid as thats what rails does anyways
  <<: *default
```

This avoids potential developer wars. You can use DotEnv to load different ENV vars for each environment. Alternatively you can add another hash to to your database.yml and merge it:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5

local_settings: &local_settings
  # will raise an exception on nil instead of failing silently
  username: <%= ENV.fetch('POSTGRESQL_USER') %> 
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  <<: *local_settings
  database: OurApplication_development

test:
  <<: *default
  <<: *local_settings
  database: OurApplication_test

production:
  # doing url: is just stupid as thats what rails does anyways
  <<: *default
```